# Blazor application with identity doesn't create account controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, blazor

I created blazor app. Implemented aspnet identity. I can register, login. But now I want to enable email confirmation and password reset. For that I need to have accountr controller which is default for aspnet identity. But there is no way to implement it. How I should be able to get that 'default' controller?

Comment: When you create a new Blazor App (Server or ASP.NET Core hosted WebAssembly) using the default templates, with "Individual User Accounts" authentication enabled, you get all that stuff for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [Scaffold RegisterConfirmation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-registerconfirmation) and configure an Email provider.

[Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Figured this out yesterday myself, took some time, but everything is working. Still, thanks for the great answer.